# Highlight active link while scrolling to the specific div in NEXTJS 13

Tags: next.js13

I am creating a single page portfolio website and each section have id like (about, contact).
and there is navbar like About, Contact so whenever i click on navbar item then i am scrolling to the specific div based on id. But my problem is when i click on 'About' then i am scrolling to the 'About' Div but how can i highlight the color of active navbar item.

There is usePathname hook inside nextjs13 but it is used when we have mutliple pages. but in my case it is a single page portfolio website.

Comment: Using `window.location.hash` can be utiltized, but since Next 13+ is rendered first on the server, the windsor object doesnt exist.  So, you have to initialize the active link state in a useEffect.  This causes the link to initially be inactive for a second.  Lame.  I hope you find an answer and share :)